# Is there any relationship between panic out of memory and linux OOM killer?

Tags: go

I am wondering if they are any relationship between panic "out of memory" in Go and Linux OOM killer.
Can both happen if memory leaks? If so then which one is run and what does it depend on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"out of memory" happens when the process exceeds the per-process limits or if the system runs out of memory. The OOM killer will be activated only if the system runs out of memory. Memory leaks can be the cause of such problems, but they are not the only possible cause.